# Exporting OpenStreet map to Image - Using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

I know Google Maps API Terms of Service do not permit you to save their map data.

However OpenStreet does.

I want to use Google Maps API (ver 2) with the OpenStreet map layer and my own map layers - and have a button to export the map to an image.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spatial index or a space-filling-curve to make your own map.